# a simple python code to multiply for loop variable used for iteration with a constant variable gives unexpected results

Tags: python, for-loop

I just wrote a very simple program that should with each iteration multiply the iteration variable with the defined variable and then print the result.

```
x=1
>>> for i in range(3):
    x *= i
    print(x)
```

to my surprise it gives:

```
0
0
0
```

why? it should give:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Hint: what is 0 * 2?

Comment: You could get your expected result simply with `print(i)`, or perhaps `print(x * i)`…

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` in the first iteration multiplies with `i=0` and so the value of x changes to `0` and for every next iteration 0 x i = 0

This is what you actually want to do

```py
x = 1
for i in range(3):
   print(x*i)
```

```
0
1
2
```